# Map fields with the same name using Lombok

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct

I'm using Lombok in a Spring Boot application, The MongoDB object are the same as my domain model so when I do the mapping I have to specify all the field names even they are the same

```
public static Receipt toModel(MGReceipt mgReceipt) {
        return Receipt.builder()
                .id(mgReceipt.getId())
                .date(mgReceipt.getDate())
                .dueDate(mgReceipt.getDueDate())
                ...
                .build();
    }
```

Is there a way to simplfy this , and avoid to specify all the properties names from `MGReceipt` that match `Receipt` ones, with `Lombok` ? or maybe I should use another solution for the mapping like `mapstruct`

Comment: Are you using Spring Data for MongoDB? There is an @Document annotation provided by Spring Data that maps java class into a collection in MongoDB

Comment: Yes, but I have two different classes `Receipt` and   `MGReceipt`

Comment: Do both classes need to be persisted in the database? What's the relationship between the classes?

Comment: Just the `MGReceipt` who should presisted, I want to instantiate a Receipt object from it

Comment: Then MapStruct is a good option. Go for it.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) was created for. MapStruct also plays quite nicely with lombok, [as described here](https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Can-I-use-MapStruct-together-with-Project-Lombok). Also lombok's `@Builder` is supported, if you want that.

Make sure you use recent versions of both lombok and MapStruct, and don't forget to add the `lombok-mapstruct-binding` as a third annotation processor to make sure MapStruct can see everything that lombok generates.

I'm not aware of any easier/nicer framework to do such a mapping. There's also no nice way of doing it manually, as that would require some nasty reflection stuff to identify similarly named fields/getters/setters.